# Flask and WordPress on the same domain in nginx

Tags: python, wordpress, nginx, flask

I need to add Wordpress blog to my Flask site.
I tried to deploy blog to working nginx config in this way:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;

location / {
    uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/site.sock;
    include uwsgi_params;
}

location = /blog/ {
   alias /var/www/blog/;
   index index.php;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$uri?$args;
}


location ~ /blog/.+\.php$ {
   root /var/www/;
   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

# path for static files
location  /static/ {
    alias /var/www/site/static/;
    autoindex on;
    expires max;
}
}
```

But wordpress shows me only 404 page(not standart, this page was made expessially for blog and included to wordpress page)
Otherwise, I checked, that connection to database created and wp_config works.
May be I missed some setting in WP or nginx config?

Comment: According to the docs, there is a longstanding bug that `alias` and `try_files` [do not work together](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97).

Answer (score 0):

You really didn't explain what locations server what exactly, but if the problem is about `alias` with `try_files` like @Seberius mentioned, then try 
try changing

```
alias /var/www/blog/;
```

to

```
root /var/www/;
```

Then reload nginx