# Enabling wordpress with a flask app using nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx, flask

Is it possible to enable wordpress on /blog of an existing flask application using nginx? Here is the config i've been working with but not getting anywhere with it. I can get either flask or wordpress to work through nginx but
1) not both at the same time
2) not wordpress with /blog option enabled (wordpress works at / but not /blog)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 0.0.0.0; 

#### if I enable the flask app, the blog doesn't work, so how can I keep this as well as add /blog ####
    # location / {
        #   include uwsgi_params;
        #   uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/html/cr_webapp/my_app.sock;
    #}

#### if I change / to /blog, it starts looking in /usr/share/nginx/html location ####
    location = / {
        #root /var/www/html/blog;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$uri?$args;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        root /var/www/html/blog;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        root /var/www/html/blog;
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root /var/www/html/blog;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
        root /var/www/html/blog;
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

I've looked at [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452457/flask-and-wordpress-on-the-same-domain-in-nginx#) but the solution didn't work for me. Also, when I use /blog, it defaults to a --prefix location, so not sure how I can change that - [a link](https://serverfault.com/questions/920880/nginx-defaults-to-usr-share-nginx-html)

Is what I am trying to do possible? or i've been ignorant this whole time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run WordPress under the `/blog` prefix, and assuming that it's installed in a directory with the same name, you set `root` to the directory above.

Use the `^~` modifier, and nested location blocks for anything that belongs to WordPress. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

```
location ^~ /blog {
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$uri?$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

Assuming that your existing flask configuration works, these lines should be fine:

```
location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/html/cr_webapp/my_app.sock;
}
```

The following lines are unrelated to WordPress or flask. If the files exist, set a value for `root` which points to where the files are located.

```
location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}
location = /robots.txt {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you sooo much! That enabled the blog home page but /blog/wp-admin doesn't show up. /wp-admin worked with only blog running. Is there a wild card or some way to enable the admin page for wordpress? The page is getting redirected to   
    http://192.168.1.106/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.106%2Fblog%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

Comment: And explicitly going to blog/wp-login  opens the login page but doesn't login (404 after hitting login). Could it be a setting within wordpress mysql database?

Comment: WordPress will need to be configured with the correct path (see [Changing The Site URL](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/)).