# Hosting flask app on subdomain (with WordPress hosted on main domain)

Tags: python, flask, subdomain, namecheap

I hope you can help with the following as I’ve been struggling to make it work for many days now.

To give you a little background, I used to host a flask app on my website domain.xyz. It is hosted on namecheap and runs via the CPanel Python App.
I then decided to also have a WordPress on the same site, so I had to move the flask to the subdomain api.domain.xyz

Now, the Wordpress site works, as does the root page of the flask app (api.domain.xyz). However, all other routes of the flask give me the same error page:

„ Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.“

Im Hosting with Namencheap, and have tried many times the support, it they insist that it’s a code Problem. What am I doing wrong?

Here’s the python code:

```
    #main.py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, abort
import os
from flask import g
import time
import socket

app = Flask(__name__, subdomain_matching=True)
#app.config["APPLICATION_ROOT"] = "/api"
#app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    print("before request")
    g.start = time.time()
    

@app.route('/test', subdomain="api", methods=['GET'])
def test():
    return '''api'''
    
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    print("HOME")
    return '''<p>This is the root page.</p>'''
 

@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    diff = time.time() - g.start
    print ("Request time: " + str(diff))
    if ((response.response) and
        (200 <= response.status_code < 300) and
        (response.content_type.startswith('text/html'))):
        response.set_data(response.get_data().replace(
            b'__EXECUTION_TIME__', bytes(str(diff), 'utf-8')))
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='api.domain.xyz', debug=True)
```

So basically, api.domain.xyz routs properly and writes „this is the root page“, while api.domain.xyz/test shows the error. In particular, not even the before_request code gets called (as I can tell from the logs), which tells me it never makes it to the code.

Any help is hugely appreciated!

Comment: use [nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57322478/enabling-wordpress-with-a-flask-app-using-nginx)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don’t think my provider (namecheap) offers this for now

Comment: shared hosting ("stellar" plan)

Comment: tried removing `subdomain="api"` from `/test` route?

Comment: thanks again for your suggestion, I fixed it eventually (see my solution below)

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if this is your issue but flask may be failing to find your flask program so in the directory with the program in (as well as any virtual environment used is activated) run:

```
export FLASK_APP=<Your Python Program Name>
```

You can test if it found your program by running

```
flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

Sorry if this does not work but this is a fairly simple solution but has happened a few times.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately that did no solve it..
I'm still thinking, because the root page is shown properly, but no logs for other pages, there must be something wrong when routing

Comment: Is this just running on your computer or as a webserver such as apache?

Comment: It’s running on namecheap Webhosting which I believe is on Apache

Comment: Do you have access to the apache files since you may have two websites on one port and you need to disable one possibly

Comment: I do not think i have, but I can set redirects as follows:
[link](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9678/2237/how-to-redirect-subdomain-to-a-certain-ip-address-along-with-a-port/). Does this help?

Comment: Quick question, when deployed `if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='api.domain.xyz', debug=True)` is this line changed to make sure you are on the correct hostname?

Comment: Yes it points to the correct subdomain of my server (no port though)

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the code was OK, however the folder structure was not correct. It seems that for every route in flask, there needs to be the respective folders in the folder structure. In my case, where I had before

```
├── api.domain.xyz
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── passenger_wsgi.py
│   ├── public
│   ├── tmp
```

I had to add a separate folder for every route, in my example above:

```
    ├── api.domain.xyz
    │   ├── main.py
    │   ├── passenger_wsgi.py
    │   ├── public
    │   ├── tmp
    │   ├── test
```

Were you to add deeper routes (say "@app.route('/test/v1/resources', subdomain="api", methods=['GET'])", you'd need to add the folder

```
│   ├── test/v1/resources
```

as well.

Answer (score 0):

1 - A site in wordpress in the root of the directory, which has a standard wordpress .htaccess.

2 - An application running in the subfolder "panel", which has a .htaccess and works with the cpanel API to create subdomains in that same folder.

Problem:
When the cPanel API is triggered, the wordpress .htaccess file does not let the API enter the subfolder "panel" and create the subdomain. When I remove the .htaccess file from wordpress from the root, the API works 100%

**`Solution--`**

may be this will work:
I am using godaddy deluxe hosting and its working in my case.

in your folder create a .htaccess and put this code:

```
RewriteEngine off
```

or

in your main .htaccess file you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/?
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).